# Timestamp value in C# differs from java

Tags: java, c#, web-services, simpledateformat

I am trying to get a timestamp value from a webservice in **C#** and then match it to a **Java** application. However, I am getting a different value in the millisecond part. There is a specific format of the timestamp on the web service so I need to convert the actual timestamp that I am getting and convert it to a string type to be able to get the proper format.

This is the timestamp from a web service

> 2017-02-09 P14:01:53.1719701+8

My sample code in java

```
    Date webServiceTimeStamp=service.getApplication().getTimestamp().getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd aHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX");
    String formattedTimeStamp = formatter.format(webServiceTimeStamp);
     if(formattedTimeStamp.contains("AM"))
     {
         formattedTimeStamp = formattedTimeStamp.replace("AM", "A");
     }else{

            formattedTimeStamp = formattedTimeStamp.replace("PM", "P");
     }
     formattedTimeStamp = formattedTimeStamp.replace("+0", "+");


    System.out.println("timestamp => " + formattedTimeStamp);
```

Output

> timestamp => 2017-02-09 P14:01:53.0000172+8

Is there a way I can get the same millisecond value from the web service? Can anyone help me on how can I get the same value so I will be able to match it to my code. Thank you so much!

Comment: It would help if you add the formatter you're using as well... Seems like the miliseconds from the service are treated as nano-seconds instead.

Comment: Hi, i just edited the code and added the formatter

Comment: will I be able to get the nano-seconds value without updating anything on the web service?

Comment: In Java, the uppercase `S` format specifier means **millisecond**, not fractional second with arbitrary number of decimals. [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn't support fractional seconds. You should never do anything but exactly 3 `S`, i.e. `SSS`, and you should never give a value with more or less than 3 digits. For nanosecond precision or any other fractional length, use the new `java.time` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Millisecond only has 3 digits of precision, so using `SSSSSSS` will always pad the miliseconds with zero's in front...

If you really want 6 digits (nanoseconds) using only millisecond precision, use this format instead:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd aHH:mm:ss.SSS'000'X")
```

Comment: Thanks, just saw your comment right after I suggested the answer ;)

Comment: @FrederikHeremans still not getting the exact value, **webservice :** _2017-02-09 P15:16:06.8347887+8_ , ** formattedtimestamp** **:** _2017-02-09 P15:16:06.835000+8_

Comment: As @Andreas mentioned: For nanosecond precision or any other fractional length, use the new java.time classes. So use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` implementations instead: `DateTimeFormatter.ofFormat("...nnnnnn")`, using `n` for nanoseconds...

Comment: @FrederikHeremans I am now getting  "Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds" error

Comment: `Date webServiceTimeStamp=qr.getApplication().getTimestamp().getTi‌​me(); LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(webServiceTimeStamp.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()); java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter=java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy‌​-MM-dd aHH:mm:ss.SSS'000'X"); String formattedTimeStamp = ldt.format(formatter);`